# Having trouble with Keyboard Events in Java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to use a KeyBoardEvent honestly just for testing purposes.. what I'm doing does not seem to be working :/ Hopefully you guys can tell me where I'm derping. Thanks!

```
package com.dillyg10.test.Keys;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Keys extends JPanel implements KeyListener  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Keys(){

    }

    public static void registerEvent(Window w){
        w.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        w.setFocusable(true);
        w.addKeyListener(new Keys());
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public static void gui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keys");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        registerEvent(new Window(frame));


        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                gui();
            }
        });
     }
    }
```

This code is basically a test to determine if the keyboardevents work, i jsut print out the key when it's pressed.. but nothing is printed.

Comment: Are you getting any `Exception`s?

Comment: Besides, check your console(in this case the command prompt or terminal) for a output, not your GUI.

Comment: I am not sure about this, hence I am just posting it as a comment, but did you try and replace this line: `w.addKeyListener(new Keys());` with this: `w.addKeyListener(this);`?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
package com.java.tests;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Keys extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static Keys keys = new Keys();

public Keys() {
}

public void registerEvent(Window w) {
    w.addKeyListener(this);
    w.setSize(200,200);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void gui() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keys");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    registerEvent(frame);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            keys.gui();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `w.addKeyListener(new Keys());` use `w.addKeyListener(this);`

Hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I got the chance to test this out and this does not work. I failed to notice that the method is marked `static`, which means that the `this` keyword will break the compilation of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Took liberty to make some changes to your code and managed to get it to work:

package sample.examples;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Keys extends JPanel implements KeyListener  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Keys(){
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button Pressed: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {       

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      

    }
    public void gui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keys");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);      


        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Keys k = new Keys();
                k.gui();
            }
        });
     }
    }
```

One of your problems seems to have been the fact that you where not specifying any size to the `JPanel`, so, regardless of where you click you where never clicking on the `JPanel`. To make it easier for you, I coloured the `JPanel` black.